# User choosable mandatory (negative) surcharge

Tags: orders, discount

I wish to define a mandatory product with options which has a negative (percentual) price.

The "discount" should be visible in the cart.

Just to be specific: customers can choose a "product delivery time" (which is the time needed to actually "create" the product which is 100% personalized + the shipping time); let's say:

- `48h delivery you pay 100%`
- `4 days you own a 20% discount`
- `7 days 30% discount`
- ...

Do you know a way to configure magento, an existing extension or a way to develop one for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly than this is already possible in Magento.

You can create a Shopping Cart Price Rule to apply a discount depending on what shipping method has been chosen. Go to:

```
Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules
```

Use the conditions tab to specify a certain shipping method.

Here is a good article on [creating custom shipping methods](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/)

Comment: nice but this would not show up in the cart. Customers will percive the advantage only at the last step of checkout pipeline.

Comment: You need to change "would not show up in the cart" to "This is advertising material"... seriously, use this as a time to educate buyers, market it as a discount, savings or something with a positive spin on it. It's not that hard to include a CMS banner with your heade ... "Choose 4-Day shipping and save 30% on delivery" "Need it ASAP, no surcharge!"

Answer (score 0):

Use custom options/configurable product and you can show the price(s) you want in the Product/List page.
Set variants as selectable options and get the effect you want.